# Story identification - Futuristic architecture of the 1950s US influenced by aliens

Tags: story-identification, architecture

I recall reading a back cover synopsis of a novel or maybe just a short story (more likely a shorter story as part of an anthology) about the futuristic architecture of the 1950s or 1960s United States actually being influenced by aliens.  The idea was that the architects didn't just dream up these designs, they were influenced by aliens, maybe seeing pictures of alien buildings or maybe having visited other planets.  I think the buildings in the story were roadside diners and motels but I'm mostly guessing here.  Unfortunately I don't recall any other details, not even a cover.  I'm guessing I ran across this story in the 1980s or 1990s but I don't know when it was written.  I'd appreciate hearing from anyone who knows about this story.

Comment: Reminds me a little of William Gibson's [*The Gernsback Continuum.*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gernsback_Continuum)

Comment: @Joe - I don't **think** this is it, but I could definitely have gotten some of the details wrong here.  I will check it out, reading some Gibson stories should be worth it in any case.  Thanks.